# How could i Select a Range of Slides in Powerpoint (VBA)

Tags: vba, vbscript, powerpoint

I Edit a VBa Code to crop all pictures in active power point or a specific slides but when i want to specify a range (like from slide 8 To 40 ) i tried like bellow:

```
    Sub Auto_pic_crop()
    Dim oshp As Shape
    Dim osld As Slide
    Dim Istart As Integer
    Dim Iend As Integer
    Istart = ActivePresentation.Slides.Range(Array(8))
    Iend = ActivePresentation.Slides.Range(Array(40))
    For Each osld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    Do While (ActivePresentation.Slides.Range() > Istart) And (ActivePresentation.Slides.Range() < Iend)
    For Each oshp In osld.Shapes
    If oshp.Type = msoPicture Then
    oshp.Width = in2Points(9.77)
    oshp.Height = in2Points(4.47)
    With oshp.PictureFormat
    .Crop.PictureWidth = in2Points(9.69)
    .Crop.PictureHeight = in2Points(5.83)
    .Crop.ShapeWidth = in2Points(9.64)
    .Crop.ShapeHeight = in2Points(4.49)
    .Crop.ShapeLeft = in2Points(0.2)
    .Crop.ShapeTop = in2Points(0.77)
    .Crop.PictureOffsetX = in2Points(0)
    .Crop.PictureOffsetY = in2Points(-0.12)
    End With
    End If
    If oshp.Type = msoPlaceholder Then
    If oshp.PlaceholderFormat.ContainedType = msoPicture Then
    End If
    End If
    Next oshp
    Loop
    Next osld
    End Sub

    Function in2Points(inVal As Single) As Single
    in2Points = inVal * 72
    End Function
```

i got Error on compiler.
Do any one could help me by edit this or any another way??
note* : I am Beginner with VBa :)

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Argument not optional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some changes to make it run and tried to keep basic frame of the code intact. You may further develop according to your need *(to modify the objects and their properties)*.  Kindly always use auto-complete while typing code. It helps someone to stick to correct properties or methods of any object.

```
    Sub Auto_pic_crop()

    Dim Shp As shape
    Dim Sld As Slide
    Dim Istart As Integer
    Dim Iend As Integer
        'Istart = ActivePresentation.Slides.Range(Array(8))
        'Iend = ActivePresentation.Slides.Range(Array(40))
        'Simply loop through slode nos I could not Understand Range(Array()) part
        Istart = 2   'change according to yuor need
        Iend = 4     'change according to yuor need

        For X = Istart To Iend
        Set Sld = ActivePresentation.Slides(X)

            For Each Shp In Sld.Shapes
            If Shp.Type = msoPicture Then
            'Shp.Width = in2Points(9.77)
            'Shp.Height = in2Points(4.47)
                With Shp.PictureFormat
                ' I could only think about four type of crop property and
                .CropLeft = in2Points(0.2)
                .CropTop = in2Points(0.77)
                .CropRight = in2Points(0.2)
                .CropBottom = in2Points(0.2)
                End With
            End If

            'No action found attached to the Code below
            If Shp.Type = msoPlaceholder Then
            If Shp.PlaceholderFormat.ContainedType = msoPicture Then
            End If
            End If

            Next Shp
        Next X
        End Sub

Function in2Points(inVal As Single) As Single
    in2Points = inVal * 72
    End Function
```